# Reduce if else statement in my ussd application

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a ussd application where I generate an interface and with predefined options e.g 1. my account 2. transactions 3. bill enquiry. the user keys in either 1 or 2 or 3 or any other predefined option on their handset. now since the input from all interfaces is the same values, to keep track of the user's progress i have states i set each time a user navigates to a certain interface. now my problem is the states are becoming too many I have about 30 states and the if else statement is starting to look like one big ball of spaghetti plus not forgetting this approach is not scalable. any one can help me do a better design probably one that's scalable.

```
if (state == 35) {//exit application
    a = mm.exit(uid);
    out.println(a);
} else if (state == 3) {
    a = view.main_menu_nav(uid, value.trim());
    out.println(a);
} else if (state == 4) {
    a = view.my_account(uid);
    out.println(a);
} else if (state == 5) {
    a = view.my_account_nav(uid, value.trim());
    out.println(a);
} else if (state == 6) {
    String value = USSD_STRING;
    a = view.transaction_nav(uid, value.trim());
    out.println(a);
} else if (state == 7) {
    a = view.deactivate_nav(uid, value.trim());
    out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: why not use switch case?

Answer (score 0):

In your example snippet, there's repetition of `out.println(a)` in each clause of the `if`, you can simplify the code by moving `out.println(a)` outside of the `if`. You could also use a `switch` instead of an `if`.
Neither of these ideas fundamentally improve the design, however.

I would suggest you look at the "[State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)" design pattern. Essentially, you have a separate object for each state that knows how to handle interactions in that state, and an outer container that receives events, holds a reference the current state object, and delegates the events to it.

A second (orthogonal) suggestion is to name your methods to reveal *intentions*—i.e. behavior. The method `deactivate_nav()` is OK, but `my_account(uid)` does not say what the method *does*.

It's hard to give specific advice without more information on your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map` and let the key be the state, the value is an object of an interface, e.g. `StateAction` which provides a proper method which you then call:

```
StateAction action = stateActions.get(state);

action.execute();
```

The interface would be defined as

```
interface StateAction
{
    void execute();
}
```

The map can be filled programmatic:

```
stateActions.put(35, new StateAction
{
    public void execute()
    {
        //exit application
        YourType a = mm.exit(uid);
        out.println(a);
    }
});

stateActions.put(3, new StateAction
{
    public void execute()
    {
        YourType a = view.main_menu_nav(uid, value.trim());
        out.println(a);
    }
});

// and so on ...
```

It's also possible to create a class for your action and let it implement the interface:

```
class AccountHandler implements StateAction
{
    // ...

    public void execute()
    {
        YourType a = view.my_account(uid);
        out.println(a);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Add this with

```
stateActions.put(4, new AccountHandler());
```

Comment: this is a great idea let me try it now see how it turns out